# Adobe Illustrator exporting layers to pdf

Tags: print-design, print-production

Hi fellow designers!!

I've created a design in Adobe Illustrator and exported a PDF file that needs to be sent to the print shop where they can open it in Acrobat Pro DC.

The design is a folder that needs to be die-cutted and folded. I've created separate layers in Adobe Illustrator - with lines indicating where to cut or fold - and when they print I'm hoping that people can hide these layers so the lines won't get printed.

I've tried to open the exported PDF in Acrobat Pro DC - but I couldn't see the layers. Is there anything I need to take notice of while exporting PDF from Illustrator?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

OK this is fun - the moment you post a question is when you start to find out for yourself - but in case anyone else finds this information helpful -

**Saving a PDF from Adobe Illustrator with layers adjustable in Acrobat Pro DC:**

- Set up your illustration so that the adjustable elements (those you
  want to show and hide) are in separate top-level layers, not nested
  within sublayers.
- Save the file in Adobe PDF format.
- In the Save Adobe PDF dialog box, choose Acrobat 8 (1.7) or Acrobat 7
  (1.6) for Compatibility.
- Make sure to check the box before "Create Acrobat Layers from Top-Level Layers", and click Save PDF.

**Opening a PDF and viewing its layers in Acrobat Pro DC:**

- Information can be stored on different layers of a PDF. The layers
  that appear in the PDF are based on the layers created in the
  original application.
- Choose View > Show/Hide > Navigation Panes > Layers.

Hope you're all having a good day
:P

Acrobat Pro DC: Show or hide layers:

https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/pdf-layers.html

Adobe Illustrator: Create a layered PDF:

https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/creating-pdf-files.html